# Determining whether the following are valid deductions

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am reading [A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://milneopentextbooks.org/download/friendly-intro-2e-update19-pdf/) by Leary and Kristensen. This is a problem from the textbook's page number 47 and I wanted to know whether I have the right answers.

---

Let the collection of nonlogical axioms be

$$\Sigma=\{ (A(x) \wedge A(x)\to B(x,y)), A(x), B(x,y)\to A(x) \}$$
and let the rule of inference be modus ponens. The set of logical axioms is empty. For each of the following, decide if it is a deduction. If it is not a deduction, explain how you know that it is not deduction.

1. $$A(x)\\ A(x)\wedge A(x)\\ (A(x)\wedge A(x))\to B(x,y)\\B(x,y)$$
   **My attempt:** It is not a valid deduction because $A(x)\wedge A(x)$ in line 2 is neither a nonlogical axiom nor does it follow  from any rule of inference.
2. $$B(x,y)\to A(x) \\ A(x) \\ B(x,y)$$
   **My attempt:** It is not a valid deduction because $B(x,y)$ in line 3 is neither a nonlogical axiom nor does it follow from any rule of inference, namely, modus ponens.
3. $$(A(x)\wedge A(x))\to B(x,y) \\ B(x,y)\to A(x) \\ (A(x)\wedge A(x))\to A(x)$$
   **My attempt:** It is not a valid deduction because $(A(x)\wedge A(x))\to A(x)$ in line 3 is neither a nonlogical axiom nor does it follow from any rule of inference, namely, modus ponens.

---

Are my answers correct? I wanted to confirm because all of the above do not seem like valid deductions to me.

Comment: It is a bit surprising that none of the three is a valid deduction, but that is the case for the reasons you have given. I think that the second example just tests your understanding of how modus ponens works (i.e., not like that), while the first and third emphasise the point that without any logical axioms, our intuitions about the meaning of $\land$ and $\to$ do not apply - modus ponens tells us something about $\to$, but not everything.

Comment: All your work is correct. Good job!